# Iterate through a list in sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I'm not familiar with sharepoint and I've been asked to do the following task. Im okay with writing c# code though. Does this question mean I need to create a class called Employee Cars, with these properties: Make, Model, Registration, Year of Production and create a list of that object and iterate through my list? If that's the case I know how to do that but I'm not sure how this works in sharepoint. Could you please also send me some references about sharepoint so I get familiar with how to do this task on sharepoint.
Here is the question:
A SharePoint 2013 Custom List, Employee Cars, contains entries for each employee of the company. Using the SharePoint Client Object Model (CSOM), Write a program to iterate through each car in the list, where the production year is greater than 2005.  The List contains the following fields: Make (String), Model (String), Registration (String) and Year of Production (Int). Use the sheet provided to show your answer.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Text;


namespace EmployeeCarsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         ClientContext spContext = new ClientContext("http://ExampleSharePointURL");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code sample:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("<site url>"))
{

    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employee Cars"); //get List by its title
    var qry = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='Year_x0020_of_x0020_Production' /><Value Type='Integer'>2005</Value></Gt></Where></Query></View>" };  //construct the query: [Production Year] > 2005, Year_x0020_of_x0020_Production is the internal name for a field 
    var items = list.GetItems(qry);  //get items using the specified query
    ctx.Load(items); // tell SharePoint to return list items  
    ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //submit query to the server 

    //print results
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item.FieldValues["Model"]);
    }
 }
```

To get acquainted with SharePoint CSOM API please follow the article [How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you please tell me what this line means?             ClientContext spContext = new ClientContext("http://ExampleSharePointURL")

Comment: This line is intended for initialization of client context which is used for performing operations against SharePoint from the client

Comment: This may be a newer version, but in my version ClientContext does not inherit from IDisposable so a using statement is not valid.

Comment: @VadimGremyachev how to iterate through the Listitemcollection if the internal name of the column is different from the display name and it's not known.